# How to wash fresh fish properly to reduce its smell?

Tags: fish, deep-frying

I want to know how can we reduce the smell of fresh fish(may be caught 5-6 hour before). It smells really bad and after deep fry its remain in it. Some people use wheat flour mixed with white vinegar to wash it. But that does not works, we tried.

Comment: Fresh fish that smells bad is not a good sign. Are you sure it's not the smell from where they were swimming that's bad and not the fish itself?

Comment: How are you storing the fish (for 5 or 6 hours)?

Comment: Natural smell of fish.  @Rob

Comment: I am talking about fresh fish available in market (In Pakistan and India). And its possible time that may be fish got catch 5 to 6 hours before from fish farm or river @wumpusD'00m

Comment: They keep fish in ice @wumpusD'00m

Comment: Fish that was caught today and has been kept on ice should not "smell really bad"; it should smell faintly of the ocean/river, and should otherwise be mild.  What kind of fish is this?  Where is it being caught?

Comment: I am asking about that smell after the fish being cooked. I caught a carp from a local river in Pakistan. @FuzzyChef

Comment: If the fish smells terrible the day you caught it, it's probably not safe to eat.

Answer (score 2):

The smell is caused by a substance called trimethylamine. You can remove the trimethylamine by rinsing the fish under cold water, or use acids. A bit of vinegar or lemon juice throughout the cooking process makes for less fishy fish (this is why lemon pairs so well with seafood). Consider finishing with an acidic sauce (such as tartar sauce).